# PostgreSQL - MAX() from upcoming dates

Tags: sql, postgresql, max

I am trying to write a query which will show me what is the maximum value starting from a date.

Example:

```
╔════════════╦═══════╦═══════════════╗
║    date    ║ value ║ max uplcoming ║
╠════════════╬═══════╬═══════════════╣
║ 01/01/2020 ║  3000 ║          4000 ║
║ 02/01/2020 ║  3000 ║          4000 ║
║ 03/01/2020 ║  3000 ║          4000 ║
║ 04/01/2020 ║  4000 ║          4000 ║
║ 05/01/2020 ║  4000 ║          3000 ║
║ 06/01/2020 ║  2000 ║          3000 ║
║ 07/01/2020 ║  2000 ║          3000 ║
║ 08/01/2020 ║  3000 ║          3000 ║
║ 09/01/2020 ║  3000 ║          2000 ║
║ 10/01/2020 ║  2000 ║          2000 ║
║ 11/01/2020 ║  2000 ║          1000 ║
║ 12/01/2020 ║  1000 ║          1000 ║
║ 13/01/2020 ║  1000 ║               ║
╚════════════╩═══════╩═══════════════╝
```

Comment: As mhawke has already mentioned, sample data is better presented as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking tables.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you're looking for the `RANGE` definitions (doc [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html))

and with the data created as

```
create table next_days (dat date, val int );
insert into next_days values('2020-01-01',3000);
insert into next_days values('2020-01-02',3000);
insert into next_days values('2020-01-03',3000);
insert into next_days values('2020-01-04',4000);
insert into next_days values('2020-01-05',4000);
insert into next_days values('2020-01-06',2000);
insert into next_days values('2020-01-07',2000);
insert into next_days values('2020-01-08',3000);
insert into next_days values('2020-01-09',3000);
insert into next_days values('2020-01-10',2000);
insert into next_days values('2020-01-11',2000);
insert into next_days values('2020-01-12',1000);
insert into next_days values('2020-01-13',1000);
```

and the query starting from `1 day` following and the end of the dataset

```
select *, 
max(val) OVER (ORDER BY dat RANGE BETWEEN '1 day' FOLLOWING  and UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) 
from next_days;
```

with results

```
    dat     | val  | max  
------------+------+------
 2020-01-01 | 3000 | 4000
 2020-01-02 | 3000 | 4000
 2020-01-03 | 3000 | 4000
 2020-01-04 | 4000 | 4000
 2020-01-05 | 4000 | 3000
 2020-01-06 | 2000 | 3000
 2020-01-07 | 2000 | 3000
 2020-01-08 | 3000 | 3000
 2020-01-09 | 3000 | 2000
 2020-01-10 | 2000 | 2000
 2020-01-11 | 2000 | 1000
 2020-01-12 | 1000 | 1000
 2020-01-13 | 1000 |     
(13 rows)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a window function:

```
SELECT max(value)
          OVER (ORDER BY date DESC
                ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING
                         AND 1 PRECEDING)
          AS "max uplcoming",
       ...
```